# Using WinHttpClients from Apache Http Components

Tags: java, apache, authentication, httpclient, ntlm

I have been able to successfully authentication to a service that requires ntlm authentication when using the WinHttpClients and a GET request. However when I try to do a POST I always get a 401 return code. Has anyone done this sucessfully before?

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpHost;
import org.apache.http.auth.AuthScope;
import org.apache.http.auth.NTCredentials;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.CredentialsProvider;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.CloseableHttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.client.protocol.HttpClientContext;
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicCredentialsProvider;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.WinHttpClients;


public class WindowsAuthPOst {

public static void main (String []args) throws Exception, IOException
{
    org.apache.log4j.BasicConfigurator.configure();
    CloseableHttpClient httpclient = WinHttpClients.createDefault();

    HttpHost target = new HttpHost("SomeHost.domain", 443, "https");

    HttpClientContext context = HttpClientContext.create();
    HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("/some/Service.svc");
    CloseableHttpResponse response1 = httpclient.execute(target, httpget, context);
    try {
        HttpEntity entity1 = response1.getEntity();
    } finally {
        response1.close();
    }

    // Execute an expensive method next reusing the same context (and connection)
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("/some/Service.svc");
    httppost.setHeader("SOAPAction", "Some Soap Action");
    httppost.setEntity(new StringEntity("Soap Payload"));
    CloseableHttpResponse response2 = httpclient.execute(target, httppost, context);
    try {
        HttpEntity entity2 = response2.getEntity();
    } finally {
        response2.close();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can check if it is available with.

```
    if (!WinHttpClients.isWinAuthAvailable()) {
        System.out.println("Integrated Win auth is not supported!!!");
    }
```

If not, it could be that you do not have [jna.jar](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna) in your classpath. It depends on jna and will silently return `false` on the above if it [not there, see source code](https://github.com/apache/httpclient/blob/52c68d6a4f1a14e88f9817270580bb384138040d/httpclient5-win/src/main/java/org/apache/hc/client5/http/impl/win/WinHttpClients.java).

Comment: It is available because it does work for GET just not POST

Answer (score 0):

Try with get (or options) before post. Some webservers requires that because of CORS.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/38410411/2376661

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30432646)