# HTML form method is POST but it's submitting as OPTIONS

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have a weird thing happening to say the least.

An html form that has a method of `post` when submitted is using `options` instead, here's the html code:

```
<form action="https://omitted" method="post" id="canvasForm">
    <div class="form-group" style="margin-top: 10%; text-align: center;">
        <h1>Canvas Integration</h1>
        <label style="text-align: right;" for="school_name" class="col-sm-4 control-label">School Prefix *</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="text" style="margin-right: 1%; margin-bottom: 2%; width:60%" class="form-control" name="school_name" placeholder="School Prefix" tabindex="1" required>
            <!-- <i class="fa fa-question-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i> -->
        </div>
        <label style="text-align: right;" for="code" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Code *</label>
        <div class="col-sm-6" >
            <input id="code" type="text" class="form-control" style="margin-right: 1%; margin-bottom: 2%; width:60%" name="code" tabindex="1" placeholder="code" required>
        </div>
        <label style="text-align: right;" for="code" class="col-sm-4 control-label">School Canvas URL *</label>
        <div class="col-sm-6" >
            <input id="canvas_url" type="text" class="form-control" style="margin-right: 1%; margin-bottom: 2%; width:60%" name="canvas_url" tabindex="1" placeholder="school canvas url" required>
        </div>
        <label style="text-align: right;" for="clientid" class="col-sm-4 control-label">ID *</label>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" style="margin-bottom: 2%;margin-right: 1%; width:60%" name="clientid" placeholder="ID" tabindex="1" required>
            <div class="tooltip">
                <i class="fa fa-question-circle" aria-hidden="true" >
                <img  class="tooltiptext" src="images/clientid.png" style="width: 550px"></i>
            </div>
        </div>
        <label style="text-align: right;" for="securitykey" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Key *</label>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" style="margin-right: 1%; margin-bottom: 2%; width:60%" name="securitykey" placeholder="Key" tabindex="1" required>
            <div class="tooltip">
                <i class="fa fa-question-circle" aria-hidden="true" >
                <img  class="tooltiptext" src="images/securitykey.png" style="width: 550px"></i>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <input id="redirect_url" type="hidden" class="form-control" style="margin-right: 1%; margin-bottom: 2%; width:60%;float: center;" name="redirect_url" placeholder="Canvas URL" tabindex="1" required>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group" style="text-align: center;">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-w-md" >Submit</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group" style="text-align: center;">
        <div id="response" class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

and I have some JS code that submits the form:

```
    form.onsubmit = function (e) {
        // stop the regular form submission
        e.preventDefault();

        // collect the form data while iterating over the inputs
        var data = {};
        for (var i = 0, ii = form.length; i < ii; ++i) {
          var input = form[i];
          if (input.name) {
            data[input.name] = input.value;
          }
        }
        // construct an HTTP request
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open(form.method, form.action, true);
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=UTF-8');

        // send the collected data as JSON
        xhr.send(JSON.stringify(data));

        xhr.onloadend = function (response) {
          console.log('response from server',response);
          var responseHtml = document.getElementById('response');
          if(response.target.status==400){
             responseHtml.innerHTML = '<div id="response" class="alert alert-success" role="alert" >' + response.target.response +'. Please contact edquire support team at support@edquire.com.' + '</div>';
          } else if (response.target.status==200) {
             responseHtml.innerHTML = '<div id="response" class="alert alert-success" role="alert" >' + response.target.response +'! Your Canvas resource is successfully connected with us :)' + '</div>';
          } else {
             responseHtml.innerHTML = '<div id="response" class="alert alert-success" role="alert" >' + 'Something went wrong :( Please Try Again!' + '</div>';
          }
        };
    };
```

when I submit it I can see that it's using `options` and it's not passing the input fields (check screenshot below)
[image]

Comment: this is due to Cross Origin Resource Sharing (CORS)

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Server-Side_Access_Control#Preflighted_requests

Comment: YES thank you @JaromandaX !!!

Comment: That's why when I test through postman it works but not from the HTML form, that makes sense now

Comment: by the way, given the headers you've shown in your image, that server does not allow CORS

Comment: @JaromandaX what did you look for in the header to see that?

Comment: cors headers, have you even bothered investigating the link by Phil?

Comment: nah i'll check it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's how CORS works. You are submitting a POST request to a remote host. First your browser submits an OPTIONS request to check whether the remote host accepts HTTP requests from other hosts. If it does the POST request will be submitted afterwards.

Comment: *"First your browser submits an OPTIONS request to check whether the remote host accepts HTTP requests from other hosts"* <- that's not exactly what the [pre-flight request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#Preflighted_requests) is for

Comment: To elaborate, if OP didn't change the request content-type header, there would not be a pre-flight `OPTIONS` request. Access to the remote resource is **always** determined by the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` response header (if any)

Answer (score -1):

With the rest client, every POST request is followed by a POST.
This is done to verify few things, for example :

1. Whether it is a valid request
2. if the method is supported etc.

You can find more information on another thread here: 
[What is the reason behind using OPTION request before POST on CORS requests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38375124/what-is-the-reason-behind-using-option-request-before-post-on-cors-requests)